# React: Dynamic list of Refs with conditional render currently Null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refs

I have a list of items that are conditionally rendered onto my page- I'd like each of them to have a unique ref based on their ID.

I tried creating a ref for each item within the constructor, but it seems either because the refs are created before the render, or because of my own error- each ref is set to null.

```
class EmailList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state={
      emailreports: []
    }
    props.emailreports.forEach(thing => {
      this[`${thing.id}_ref`] = React.createRef()
     });
    }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      emailreports: this.props.emailreports
    })
  }

  render() {
  const { emailreports } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      
      <section>
        <h5>Email Reports</h5>
        <ul>

          {
            emailreports.length > 0
            ?
            <>
            {
              emailreports.map((report, i) => {
                return <EmailReportItem ref={this[`${report.id}_ref`]}  />
              })
            }
            </>
            :
            <section >
              <div className="text-center">You do not currently have access to email report data.</div>
            </section>
          }
        </ul>
      </section>
  </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmailList);
```

The following image is the result of the above load:

[image: Refs]

Comment: It seems the refs are created. Where are you console logging this?

Comment: I put in a temporary button that logs `this` just to see if the refs are created. Indeed they are created- however it doesn't seem they are assigned to anything. Is this true?

Comment: How does the `EmailReportItem` component handle received refs? Have you also instead tried creating a single ref to hold an array to generated refs for each email report?

Comment: I bet if you replace `EmailReportItem` with say `input` it will work. But what are you trying to achieve? There should be a better way.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm not sure how I would do that- doesn't the forEach loop accomplish the same thing? How can that be done?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova That's definitely a possibility... I'm trying to perform a `.scrollIntoView()` on load based on the match parameters. Is there an easier way to select an element for `.scrollIntoView()`?

Comment: That's funny that you are trying to scroll elements into view, the example I was going to try and share is essentially exactly this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64981228/8690857 It uses functional components to the main ref used to store the array of refs is created from the `useRef` hook, but conceptually it is the same.

Comment: As an option you can pass a flag into the component you want to scroll into view, at least each child component will keep its own single ref and you won't need to struggle with forwarding refs

Comment: What Nadia says, or you can wrap each mapped `EmailReportItem` in a div parent that consumes the ref.

Comment: Thank you both! I will give this a shot- though not entirely sure I understand. @DrewReese regarding the example provided- is it possible to use `useRef([])` in a Class based component?

Comment: No, you'd use `createRef` still to create the single main ref. Functional components need to generate it a bit differently because if they used `createRef` it would be recreated each render cycle and all the refs would be lost/reset.

Comment: Just passing a property like `<EmailReportItem shouldScroll=true />` and inside `EmailReportItem` you check the flag and scroll to an element (with a ref again, but that'll be the only ref there)

Comment: @DrewReese & Nadia you both solved it! I ended up wrapping in a div and the refs have now assigned! Thanks so much again!!!!!

Comment: Lovely, glad you solved your problem!

Comment: Welcome, glad it all works for you now.